# javascript insert space symbol to input tag and pass it with form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, shopify

Latest solution was `e.currentTarget.value = String.fromCharCode(32);`
But in this case form seems trim all spaces from input tag. Value of passed input tag is `""`(empty)

Comment: That is replacing the entire value with `" "` And you are saying you are not getting that value?

Comment: Maybe Shopify is automatically trimming all the inputs. It's very unusual for leading and trailing spaces to be significant.